# Need a good Hash function for an ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, hash, arraylist

I have an ArrayList, the ArrayList is different combinations of numbers from 1-100, now need to change it to key used in Hashmap.

Then I first translate the ArrayList to String then use a Hash function to get a number as key. But it seems very slow, can I just skip the first step (translate step), use the integer in the  doHash functions? Or any other ways to improve it? thanks

```
public static String Arraytostr(ArrayList<Integer> route) {    
     String listString = "";    
        for (Integer s : route){
            listString += s;
        }               
      return listString;

}

static long doHash(String str) {    
        long hash = 5381;    
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charAt(i);
        }    
        return hash;
}
```

Comment: Do you want hashCode?

Comment: Why not use `ArrayList#hashCode()`, which is defined by `AbstractList`?

Comment: Can you not use Java's inbuilt hash functionality? .hashCode() is far more efficient than anything you are likely to write.

Comment: Or maybe just return the first value in the array. Or the sum of the first N values. Is your current has function so slow that it's actually not meeting your performance requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the reason that you're writing your own hash, instead of using `hashCode` is so that you get a `long`, not an `int`.  If an `int` is adequate, I strongly recommend just using the `hashCode` method on `ArrayList`.

It does seem a bit odd to convert your `Integer`s to `String`s, then pick them apart character by character.  But you could just do the following, which will skip out all the expensive `Integer` to `String` conversion.

```
static long doHash(Collection<Integer> inputs) {    
    long hash = 5381;    
    for (Integer i : inputs) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + i;
    }    
    return hash;
}
```